# How much does the average person spend supporting their aged parents?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, retirement

This [Aging Without Children](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/women/family/ageing-without-children-is-scary-lonely-and-cruel---but-we-dont/) article states "Family is seen as the solution to aging". How true is this? In China it can be required by law. I live in the US and it seems like the flow of funds more often goes from grandparents' investments to strapped kids.

My main purpose in asking is wondering, "How much should a person who decided not to have children save to replace their expected contribution?"

Comment: In some families, children support the parents; in others, parents support the children and grandchildren; in others the finances are separate once the child reaches some age of majority or other milestone such as marrying. There is no way anyone can tell you "most people's retirement plans include X from their children; since you have no children, add X to the average numbers you see." I doubt any publicly available retirement advice includes any expectation of money from children, but that's really not the point.

Comment: I think your question at the end is a good one, and a problem I had never considered, but the title and start of the post is out of sync and asks a very different, rather off topic, question. With revision to focus on the last question I would +1

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. Your question is likely to be closed as either too broad or personal opinion. Keep in mind, when retirement income is listed, I've never seen "children's contribution" as part of the equation. Your benefit, if any, of not having children, is the savings you'll have from not caring for a human person over 18-22 years, including a potential $250K college bill.

Comment: The title question is not unanswerable -- a simple survey would do it. Then that information would help people develop their answer to the second question -- "most adults get by with $2000 annually from their children, so I should be OK saving that much" would be a different world from "most adults receive 5-15 years of free care and rent from their children, which would cost $180,000 to replace with long-term care". So answer the title question, I will then use the answer to answer the other, fuzzier question.

Comment: If you want to conduct a survey, that's off topic for Stack Exchange.

Comment: The real question you seem to be asking is "how much should. I save so I will be self-sufficient in retirement." This has been discussed previously and I'd recommend you read the answers to that question.

Comment: I don't want to survey SE users. I want someone to inform me of the results of a government-sponsored survey, newspaper poll, corporate fact sheet, or whatever other research bears on the question. Like asking the question "What is the average American inheritance passed on to children?" and getting [this source](http://money.cnn.com/2013/12/13/retirement/american-inheritance/) as an answer.

Comment: How much people plan to have children contribute to their retirement and how much they plan to leave their children after death are two VERY different questions.  I am not aware of anyone who plans to have their children contribute to their retirement, no person that I know WANTS to be dependent on their children.  Sometimes events require some dependence but I don't know that it is something we plan.  My personal plan is to leave my children whatever is left when my wife and I pass.  As life expectancy changes and unplanned expenses come with age it is difficult to plan a set amount to leave.

Comment: I do not want to know about plans, but actual spending. The answer will be useful for the children's forecasting as well as the childfree adult's expectations. 

There are definitely adults who [expect](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-reasonable-for-parents-to-expect-that-their-children-support-them-financially-during-their-old-age-till-they-die/answers/14541312) their children's support. Others don't plan responsibly because they know their kids will feel obligated to help.

Comment: I guess I am missing what the question is. You don't want to know about planning but you want to know how much to save to compensate for not having a child's expected contribution. Wouldn't expecting a contribution be planning on it? Under what conditions would a parent expect their child to contribute? Are we talking about it being normal or in case of unforseen circumstances? Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5):

Most people in the US don't **plan** on relying on their children financially to retire, so there is nothing additional to modify a retirement plan specifically for that.  Most people who do rely on their children do so because they **fail to plan** sufficiently for retirement.  You likely won't need significant amounts of life insurance if you have no children, which is a cost savings (not to mention not having to pay for the kids expenses themselves), but you may want to have things more clearly planned out via a will or other legal documents since there may not be a next of kin to be able to make decisions for your estate once you're gone.  It's also worth noting that you won't have the fallback of relying on kids, so failing to plan will likely end up worse for you than if you had children.

Comment: To the extent that this question is answerable, I think this is the best appropriate answer. Having a smaller support network (family, friends, etc.) means you must rely on yourself more in times of emergency. Among other things, this may mean that without children, you will need to ensure (that much more than anyone else) that you can support yourself after you retire. However any number you see on line about 'how much to save for retirement' is already assuming you will be self-sufficient, so it's not a magic number you need to add to other estimates.

Answer (score 1):

According to AARP’s [2016 Family Caregiving and Out-of-Pocket Costs Report](https://www.aarp.org/content/dam/aarp/research/surveys_statistics/ltc/2016/family-caregiving-costs.doi.10.26419%252Fres.00138.001.pdf), family caregivers roughly spend an average of $6,954 annually. They count 40 million caregivers, so only 20% of adults are paying for caregiving at any one time.

According to Genworth’s [Cost of Care Survey 2019](https://www.genworth.com/aging-and-you/finances/cost-of-care.html), the median cost for supporting a parent in assisted living or in-home care is around $4,000/month, while the median for nursing homes is around $8,000 a month. This represents an upper bound for support costs, and much of it will be borne by someone other than the children.

Both statistics were found at https://www.regions.com/Insights/Personal/Life-Stages/Empty-Nest/The-Cost-of-Caring-for-an-Elderly-Parent.

It looks to me like the median individual pays roughly zero, while a minority may pay up to $120,000 over a lifetime. So the average will probably not matter much to you as much as which group you are in.